# Within Batch Apex, how to execute query using a list view filterId

Tags: apex, batch

I am trying to pull selected view records in Batch Apex.

Can Any body give me help me, how can I make query in  **`Database.getQueryLocator();`** to pull all records of the view.

Query = `'select id,name from contact where viewId=:selectedId'`

```
Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
```

Comment: Are you trying to select the same Contact records as an existing List View or do you mean something else?

Comment: Same contact view list as it was already there in the system

Comment: Sorry Sunny, I'm not following you, can you post a screen shot on your question of what you mean please?